# PHP 5 and Zend MVC on Windows and IIS

Tags: php, windows, zend-framework, magento, iis

Are there any major issues to be aware of running a PHP 5 / Zend MVC production application on Windows? The particular application is Magento, an ecommerce system, and the client is really not interested in having a Linux box in their datacenter. Has anyone had luck getting PHP 5 and Zend MVC working correctly on IIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it works. Microsoft and Zend are working together to get PHP running as it runs on linux. Zend even has a certified version of their core package (includes php, mysql and some control panel) for Windows and iis. Also Zend Framework is supposed to be truly platform independend.

Another option instead is to use Apache on Windows, but IIS is faster for static page views and also has some other interesting options. .htaccess files are not supported, so for rewriting you need to rely on other IIS components.

Answer (score 2):

Well I got IIS, Zend and PHP all working nicely.

Installed the ReWrite module, followed :[this article](http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2006/09/19/How-to-install-PHP-on-IIS7-_2800_RC1_2900_.aspx)
Got the Zend re-write rule [from here](http://www.zendframework.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html)  and ensured short_opentag = on in my **php.ini**

So far so good

Comment: We have a client who used flex mobile app on php-zend-xammp configuration. Mobile app connects to ERP system on server. Now another client wants to use the mobile app on IIS. And client doesn't want to use zend or any other third party application but only IIS. How to go about installing PHP on IIS in that case to use the flex mobile app?

Answer (score 1):

Get the IIS ReWrite module which will make things a little easier.

http://www.iis.net/downloads/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=1691

I have Zend, PHP, Apache and MySQL running on my Vista x64 machine but I will give it a try on running it on IIS instead of Apache.

I imagine it wouldn't be too difficult

Answer (score 0):

We've also made some progress in getting Magento running on a Windows Server 2008 box with IIS7 (under ISAPI). If we disable URL rewriting the system works quite well however we've not been able to achieve success with Magento and any of rewriting systems (Helicon ISAPI Rewrite-Lite, Ape and the Microsoft Rewrite Module).

Answer (score 0):

[Magento is not supported on windows](http://www.magentocommerce.com/system-requirements). I did install it but is more complicated than linux and it makes no sense in developing in an environment that will be different than the deployment one. Your client should reconsider.