# How to use Zend Framework in Windows Server?

Tags: windows, zend-framework

I'd like to use Zend framework in my server, but it's Windows and I don't know what to do with the Rewrite Engine. In Linux I could use .htaccess but I notice that this doesn't work in Windows-based servers.

What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run Apache on your Windows server, .htaccess should work just fine. Otherwise if you're using IIS, you may find what you need here:
[PHP 5 and Zend MVC on Windows and IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543777/php-5-and-zend-mvc-on-windows-and-iis)