# Zend Framework and IIS

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework, iis

Is it possible to use Zend Framework MVC in IIS? (mode_rewrite missing)
I follow some article about this issue but not successful.
Did anybody get result? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is - you can install PHP using the Microsoft Web Platform Installer and then you should simply be able to get Zend framework running just as you would any other PHP code.

See here:

http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx

http://php.iis.net/

See this SO question also: [PHP 5 and Zend MVC on Windows and IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543777/php-5-and-zend-mvc-on-windows-and-iis)

Answer (score -1):

Yes its possible to install zend in IIS.

IIS have solution of URL rewrite problem. Visit www.iis.net/urlrewrite to get the latest copy of the plugin to attach into your IIS installation. Just install this addon/plugin/extension/demon/program whatever name you called.

After installation you need a file web.config into your “ZF2Skeleton/public” folder. No matter, here we do a small trick. Just download Drupal 7 core from https://drupal.org/project/drupal and unpack it. There you found a web.config file at root path. Just copy and paste that file into your ZF2Skeleton/public folder.

Following article will show you how you can install Zend Framework 2 into your windows OS with IIS without composer.phar help.

For More Details Visit Following Link - 
http://shkhan.wordpress.com/2014/04/26/install-zend-framework-2-into-windows-iis/

Comment: While that link may provide an answer to the question, it would be better if you could include the relevant parts in your answer (with attribution). Otherwise, your answer may become invalid if the page content is changed or removed.